# Prevent phone from powering off or power it on with alarm manager

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I have created an app which runs a `Service` with `AlarmManager`. The `Service` fires the `AlarmManager` successfully. What I have achieved until now is that the `Service` starts after phone boots and all the alarms in the `AlarmManager` are being reset. However, when the phone is powered off, the `AlarmManager` is not fired (which is logical). So, how can I turn on phone with a selected time with `AlarmManager`? While many people say it cannot be done, there is an app in my phone which was installed by factory and can do what I described above.

Comment: by turned off you mean powered off or just pressed power button (screen lock)?

Comment: @Itamar Green I mean powered off. I'm sorry, I will correct it.

Comment: Non-rooted Android devices do not have permission to power on or power off the device.

Comment: @nick friskel So, it's impossible to power on the device without root. Thus, it won't be "my fault" if a user set an alarm while phone is powered off and it doesn't fire?

Comment: You will need to keep a record of such alarms that are missed and fire/reschedule them when powered on.

Comment: @Kamran Ahmed and probably notify the user that they were missed.. ok thanks